# how to read variable URLs in servlet

Tags: java, url, servlets

i am using servlet, and i am using this URL

```
http://s4.com/api/system?section0=report&reportType0=overTime&dataType0
```

in the browser to request some json data that i create in the servlet

i tried to read the whole URL to get it is first part `s4.com` in the `doGet` method since it may came as :

```
http://s.com/api/system?section0=report&reportType0=overTime&dataType0
http://s1.com/api/system?section0=report&reportType0=overTime&dataType0
http://s2.com/api/system?section0=report&reportType0=overTime&dataType0
http://s3.com/api/system?section0=report&reportType0=overTime&dataType0
http://s4.com/api/system?section0=report&reportType0=overTime&dataType0
.
.
.
http://s100.com/api/system?section0=report&reportType0=overTime&dataType0
```

so i need to distinguish between them using the s(number).com

in the do get method i tried

```
request.getRequestURL().toString(); ===== output===> http://localhost:8090/MySim/api/system
```

and

```
request.getServerName().toString();===== output===>  localhost
```

and

```
request.getRequestURL().toString(); ===== output===> /MySim/api/system
```

and i also tried this

```
        String uri = request.getScheme() + "://" +   // "http" + "://
    request.getServerName() +       // "myhost"
    ":" +                           // ":"
    request.getServerPort() +       // "8080"
    request.getRequestURI() +       // "/people"
    "?" +                           // "?"
    request.getQueryString();
```

which prints the full path URL
  ===== output===>

```
http://localhost:8090/MySim/api/systemsection0=system&type0=shortStatus&rand0=1405835810247&sessionId=FFFFFFFFF
```

but non of these got the right answer

my a part of web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Api</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/system</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

hosts file :

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       sim.localhost
127.0.0.1       sim.nma.localhost
127.0.0.1       nma.localhost
127.0.0.1       s.com
127.0.0.1       s1.com
127.0.0.1       s2.com
127.0.0.1       s3.com
127.0.0.1       s4.com
127.0.0.1       s5.com
```

---

i am using xhamp server with apatchi so in the Config file i used to the following :

```
</VirtualHost>
        <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerName s4.com


          Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
            ProxyRequests Off
            <Proxy *>       
                Allow from all
            </Proxy>

            ProxyPass /session/             http://localhost:8090/MySim/session/
            ProxyPass /api/                 http://localhost:8090/MySim/api/


            ProxyPassReverse /session/      http://localhost:8090/MySim/session/    
            ProxyPassReverse /api/          http://localhost:8090/MySim/api/    


        </VirtualHost>
        <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerName s5.com


          Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
            ProxyRequests Off
            <Proxy *>       
                Allow from all
            </Proxy>

            ProxyPass /session/             http://localhost:8090/MySim/session/
            ProxyPass /api/                 http://localhost:8090/MySim/api/


            ProxyPassReverse /session/      http://localhost:8090/MySim/session/    
            ProxyPassReverse /api/          http://localhost:8090/MySim/api/    


        </VirtualHost>
```

this is why request.getserverName() always prints local host

and now i edited the config file  ass following :

```
</VirtualHost>
        <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerName s4.com


          Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
            ProxyRequests Off
            <Proxy *>       
                Allow from all
            </Proxy>

            ProxyPass /session/             http://s4.com:8090/MySim/session/
            ProxyPass /api/                 http://s4.com:8090/MySim/api/


            ProxyPassReverse /session/      http://s4.com:8090/MySim/session/   
            ProxyPassReverse /api/          http://s4.com:8090/MySim/api/   


        </VirtualHost>
        <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerName s5.com


          Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
            ProxyRequests Off
            <Proxy *>       
                Allow from all
            </Proxy>

            ProxyPass /session/             http://s5.com:8090/MySim/session/
            ProxyPass /api/                 http://s5.com:8090/MySim/api/


            ProxyPassReverse /session/      http://s5.com:8090/MySim/session/   
            ProxyPassReverse /api/          http://s5.com:8090/MySim/api/   


        </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client browser connects to

```
http://s4.com/api/system
```

but your web applications responds to

```
http://localhost:8090/MySim/api/system
```

That is a common use case : it means that you have a HTTP reverse proxy (commons are apache, nginx or IIS) that does the URL rewriting. If it is possible, you should ask the administrator of the proxy how and where you can find the original requested host. If this is not an option, you will have to examine all the headers to try to discover it. For example, Apache mod-proxy normally uses the header `X-Forwarded-Host`.